Choosing Between Native and Module Federation in Angular
I'm currently working on an Angular 18 project and I'm trying to decide between using Native Federation and Module Federation for my architecture. I would appreciate any guidance or insights on the following points:
Performance: How does each option impact application performance?
Complexity: Which option tends to be more complex in terms of setup and maintenance?
Scalability: Which solution is more scalable for larger applications?
Best Practices: Are there any best practices or recommendations for choosing between the two?
I’m looking forward to any suggestions or experiences you might have!
Thank you!

Module Federation is a Webpack feature. New Angular projects use ESBuild instead of Webpack. It is possible that at some point Angular deprecates or removes the Webpack builder. But this is just some guessing. You could argue that a build-tool agnostic solution is more future-proof.

Is it better to use Native Federation instead of Module Federation in my project?

What are some best practices for developing micro frontends with Angular?

In essence, both native federation and module federation enable lazy loading of modules or components at runtime that are unknown during compilation.
The key difference is that module federation relies on Webpack for both splitting and loading, which ties you to the Webpack. Although there are some new developments for RSPack as well.
On the other hand, native federation uses esbuild for splitting, but loading happens via import maps, a Web standard (https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). This makes it independent of any specific bundler.
For obvious reasons, I'd go with native federation.

I had another question: sometimes when using native federation, some libraries cannot be resolved, and errors occur. What could be the reason for this?

@CavidHaciyev In most cases that is because those libraries are not in ESM format. Imports Maps require that and if they encounter CommonJS there will be an error. In this case, check if that library has an ESM version or just don't share it.
